# Update data and relationships in Access table from Excel data

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

So I am importing data from Excel and creating new tables with the data I got from them using the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`. What I want to do is have these new tables replace the old tables in my database when I import them while keeping the relationships in-tact so I can completely automate the process with a single button. I don't think the UPDATE query method would work due to the constant adding and taking away of data (though I may be wrong since I am relatively new to SQL). I was hoping there would be a way to just delete all the data out of a table and then fill it back up again from the new tables with VBA. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Not sure how the existing tables are related, but you could always delete the existing data, then append the new. 1. Do you want to delete ALL rows in the three existing tables? 2. Are the columns imported from Excel all you need for Access?

Comment: The tables have a single one to many relationship linking them, nothing complicated. Yes, I want to delete everything in the existing tables. And yes, what is being imported from Excel is all the data I need in Access. I appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming your tables are named 'T1', 'T2', 'T3' and are in that order for relationships, try the following as one possible solution.  Just add this code (changing the table names) following your import code:

```
Dim strSQL  As String
strSQL = "delete * from T3;"     ' Delete all existing rows
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
strSQL = "delete * from T2;"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
strSQL = "delete * from T1;"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

' Insert new rows from imported tables.
strSQL = "INSERT INTO T1 SELECT Import1.* FROM Import1;
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
strSQL = "INSERT INTO T2 SELECT Import2.* FROM Import2;
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
strSQL = "INSERT INTO T3 SELECT Import3.* FROM Import3;
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! It works exactly how I want it to for 2 of the 3 tables... Unfortunately, the third is now causing me grief. For some reason when I try to use the insert function on the last table, it executes fine but when I open up the table it's completely blank. I have confirmed that the data types are the same for both tables and the new table populated correctly, the existing table just doesn't get the new data. Any advice?

Comment: Try running the SQL manually and see if you get any error. Other ideas: (a) are there any relationships that must be evaluated (i.e. is there owner records required in another table?) (b) are there any field validations required but failing?